# Fail to upload apk to beta track. Google Api Error: releaseToHaltNotFound: Cannot halt release, no matching in progress release found

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane, google-api-ruby-client

I am using fastlane to upload apks to google play beta track. I have multiple apks for different countries with different package names. 
A few days ago, it failed to upload one of my apk. 
Fastlane log:

```
[13:54:31]: WARNING: fastlane requires your locale to be set to UTF-8. To learn more go to https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#set-up-environment-variables
DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:31.49]: Checking if there are any plugins that should be loaded...
Successfully loaded Appfile at path '/Users/XXX/XXX-android/fastlane/Appfile'
- json_key_file: './fastlane/Google Play Android Developer-XXX.json'
-------
Successfully loaded Appfile at path '/Users/XXX/XXX-android/fastlane/Appfile'
- json_key_file: './fastlane/Google Play Android Developer-XXX.json'
-------
DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:31.68]: Using country: XXX
DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:31.68]: Using track: beta
DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:31.68]: Using rollout: 0.1
DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:31.68]: Using skip_upload_apk: false
DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:31.68]: Using skip_upload_metadata: true
DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:31.68]: Using skip_upload_images: true
DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:31.68]: Using skip_upload_screenshots: true
DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:31.68]: Using skip_upload_aab: true
DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:31.68]: Using validate_only: true
DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:31.68]: Using check_superseded_tracks: false
DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:31.68]: Using run_on_ci: true
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:31.69]: ----------------------------------------
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:31.69]: --- Step: Verifying fastlane version ---
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:31.69]: ----------------------------------------
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:31.69]: Your fastlane version 2.106.2 matches the minimum requirement of 2.66.0  ✅
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:31.69]: ------------------------------
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:31.69]: --- Step: default_platform ---
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:31.69]: ------------------------------
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:31.69]: Driving the lane 'android Submit_One' 
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:31.70]: --------------------
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:31.70]: --- Step: supply ---
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:31.70]: --------------------
Successfully loaded Appfile at path '/Users/XXX/XXX-android/fastlane/Appfile'
- json_key_file: './fastlane/Google Play Android Developer-XXX.json'
-------
Successfully loaded Appfile at path '/Users/XXX/XXX-android/fastlane/Appfile'
- json_key_file: './fastlane/Google Play Android Developer-XXX.json'
-------
Successfully loaded Appfile at path '/Users/XXX/XXX-android/fastlane/Appfile'
- json_key_file: './fastlane/Google Play Android Developer-XXX.json'
-------
Successfully loaded Appfile at path '/Users/XXX/XXX-android/fastlane/Appfile'
- json_key_file: './fastlane/Google Play Android Developer-XXX.json'
-------
Successfully loaded Appfile at path '/Users/XXX/XXX-android/fastlane/Appfile'
- json_key_file: './fastlane/Google Play Android Developer-XXX.json'
-------

+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              Summary for supply 2.106.2                              |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| track                   | beta                                                       |
| skip_upload_apk         | false                                                      |
| skip_upload_metadata    | true                                                       |
| skip_upload_images      | true                                                       |
| skip_upload_screenshots | true                                                       |
| skip_upload_aab         | true                                                       |
| rollout                 | 0.1                                                        |
| validate_only           | true                                                       |
| check_superseded_tracks | false                                                      |
| package_name            | com.XXX.XXX                                                |
| metadata_path           | ./fastlane/metadata/android/XXX                            |
| json_key                | ./fastlane/Google Play Android Developer-XXX.json |
| timeout                 | 300                                                        |
| deactivate_on_promote   | true                                                       |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+

DEBUG [2018-10-16 13:54:32.24]: Fetching a new access token from Google...
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:36.81]: Preparing to upload for language 'it-IT'...
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:37.28]: Validating all changes with Google Play...
WARN [2018-10-16 13:54:39.93]: Lane Context:
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:39.93]: {:DEFAULT_PLATFORM=>:android, :PLATFORM_NAME=>:android, :LANE_NAME=>"android Submit_One"}
ERROR [2018-10-16 13:54:39.93]: Google Api Error: releaseToHaltNotFound: Cannot halt release, no matching in progress release found.
INFO [2018-10-16 13:54:39.93]: Successfully generated documentation at path '/Users/XXX/XXX-android/fastlane/README.md'

+------+----------------------------+-------------+
|                fastlane summary                 |
+------+----------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                     | Time (in s) |
+------+----------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | Verifying fastlane version | 0           |
| 2    | default_platform           | 0           |
|    | supply                     | 8           |
+------+----------------------------+-------------+

ERROR [2018-10-16 13:54:39.94]: fastlane finished with errors
bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/fastlane)
FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneError: [!] Google Api Error: releaseToHaltNotFound: Cannot halt release, no matching in progress release found.
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:141:in `user_error!'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/ui.rb:17:in `method_missing'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/supply/lib/supply/client.rb:398:in `rescue in call_google_api'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/supply/lib/supply/client.rb:395:in `call_google_api'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/supply/lib/supply/client.rb:111:in `validate_current_edit!'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/supply/lib/supply/uploader.rb:39:in `perform_upload'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/upload_to_play_store.rb:33:in `run'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:50:in `execute_action'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:232:in `block in execute_action'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:227:in `chdir'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:227:in `execute_action'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:149:in `method_missing'
  Fastfile:84:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:56:in `cruise_lane'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:76:in `run!'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:333:in `run'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in `start'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:108:in `take_off'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.106.2/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/fastlane:22:in `load'
  /Users/XXX/XXX-android/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/fastlane:22:in `<top (required)>'
ERROR [2018-10-16 13:54:39.94]: WARNING: fastlane requires your locale to be set to UTF-8. To learn more go to https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#set-up-environment-variables
```

I have multiple packages. Only one has such issue.
I manually upload apk to beta track on google console. It works fine.

I use following command:

```
supply(
        track: options[:track],
        skip_upload_apk: options[:skip_upload_apk],
        skip_upload_metadata: options[:skip_upload_metadata],
        skip_upload_images: options[:skip_upload_images],
        skip_upload_screenshots: options[:skip_upload_screenshots],
        skip_upload_aab: options[:skip_upload_aab],
        rollout: options[:rollout],
        validate_only: options[:validate_only],
        check_superseded_tracks: options[:check_superseded_tracks],
        package_name: package_name,
        metadata_path: metadata_path,
        apk: apk
        )
```

Comment: Hi, have the same problem, any update?